# Monitor Outbound Webservice calls

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, network-monitoring

I'm currently debugging a 3rd party component and I need to monitor to see if it is making an outbound webservice call. Does anyone know of a way of quickly setting up something to monitor this as I step over the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would get wireshark. It can trace network packets, its a quick install.

http://www.wireshark.org/

Answer (score 1):

Old but good and completely free: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/smsniff.html

Answer (score 1):

Try fiddler, easier to use than wireshark if this is new to you.